# Computer goes directly to Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

Last night I installed Ubuntu using the online Windows installer `Wubi.exe`, my hard disk has 3 partitions, disk `C:` with Windows OS, disk `D:` where Ubuntu was installed and disk `E:`
everything went smooth and when finished, the computer was rebooted, but afterwards, every boot it goes directly to Windows.

What do I have to do to get to the screen that shows the OS options so I can choose Ubuntu?

Comment: which windows version?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem might be EasyBCD. This software enables you to edit your windows bootloader and dualboot to your hearts content (this is according to them). I have used EasyBCD successfully in the past and hope it works for you.

The solution to your problem can be found [here](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu) hope it helps!